# How to create a popup on domain-1 with contents from domain-2 using jquery/iframe/or any other thing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I will explain my problem in steps to be clear.

1. I have a domain-1 where I want to past an iframe/javascript or something
2. Then I want a popup to show up whenever domain-1 loads, this popup is in the center and covers the whole screen (with faded background)
3. the content on this popup is from another domain-2.

I know there is same origin policy issue, I have also seen this question [Cross domain popup window with return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443142/cross-domain-popup-window-with-return-value) but could not understand what/how the webservice can be made.

EDIT:

I will explain it further...

I want to put an iframe in website1 ... as soon as website1 loads I want a popup to cover the whole page like this: http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/

Now this popup contains content from website2

Comment: you can use an iframe cross domain, policies have to do with scripting inside the iframe

Comment: can you please explain how? thanks

Comment: I really don't understand the problem...post a demo in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get('/some/page.html', function(data) {
  $('#result').html(data);
});
```